# Select multiple columns but apply Avg() with only one column?

Tags: oracle

How to return the program name, campus name, tuition fee of the program, and the average tuition fee for all the programs that are taught on the each campus?

```
CREATE TABLE Campus
(
    Campus_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Campus_Name    varchar(24),
    Campus_Address varchar(24),
    Campus_City varchar(12)
);

CREATE TABLE Program
(
    Program_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Program_Name varchar(24),
    Program_Description varchar(2000),
    Tuition_Fess numeric(7,2),
    Program_Coordinator_ID INTEGER,
    Campus_ID INTEGER
);
```

This is what I expected but didn't work since `group by` needs every columns that being used.

```
SELECT 
Program.Program_Name,
Campus.Campus_Name,
Program.Tution_Fees,
AVG(Program.Tution_Fees) AS AVERAGE
FROM Program
INNER JOIN Campus
ON Program.Campus_ID=Campus.Campus_ID
GROUP BY Campus.Campus_Name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something called 'window functions'. They're similar to 'aggregate functions', but the act on every row (partitioning by some field value). I'm sure you will find out how to do it if you check the documentation. You're code will end up looking something like:

```
SELECT Program.Program_Name,
    Campus.Campus_Name,
    Program.Tution_Fees,
    AVG(Program.Tution_Fees) OVER(PARTITION BY Campus_ID) AS CAMPUS_AVERAGE
FROM Program
    INNER JOIN Campus
    ON Program.Campus_ID=Campus.Campus_ID
;
```

Comment: This is the final answer!   
`SELECT P.Program_Name, C.Campus_Name, P.Tution_Fees, AVG(P.Tution_Fees) OVER(PARTITION BY C.Campus_Name) AS CAMPUS_AVERAGE FROM Program P INNER JOIN Campus C ON P.Campus_ID = C.Campus_ID;`   
But I got the Idea from your code. You saved my life thanks!!

Comment: I removed the GROUP BY clause at the end, since it didn't belong there. Also for terminology, the functions are called ***analytic*** functions (rather than "window" functions).

Comment: @mathguy Thank you, but they're also (and mainly) called 'window functions' in official documentations for postgreSQL, Mariadb, Mysql and even Microsoft SQL Server, as well as in ANSI SQL definitions.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The post is tagged as Oracle database, not the other products you mention. In Oracle database, the functions are called analytic functions.